# On click get value of this container values

Tags: javascript, jquery

Used below HTML & JS to get 'from city code' and 'to city code' on click 'search-content'.

Not sure, why logic is not getting value correctly. It gets only first time value. On clicking of 2nd 'search-content', still i am getting 1st item value.

Can any one please suggest a solution to solve this issue?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="search--container">
  <div class="title">Recent searches:</div>
  <div class="search-content">
    <div class="location">
      <div class="from-city--code">KUL</div>
      <div class="sep">-</div>
      <div class="to-city--code">HKG</div>
    </div>
    <div class="date">
      <div class="from-date" data-departdate="21 May 2017">21/05</div>
      <div class="sep">-</div>
      <div class="to-date" data-returndate="29 May 2017">29/05</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="search-content">
    <div class="location">
      <div class="from-city--code">MAS</div>
      <div class="sep">-</div>
      <div class="to-city--code">SIN</div>
    </div>
    <div class="date">
      <div class="from-date" data-departdate="14 Jun 2017">14/06</div>
      <div class="sep">-</div>
      <div class="to-date" data-returndate="21 Jun 2017">21/06</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="search-content">
    <div class="location">
      <div class="from-city--code">LDN</div>
      <div class="sep">-</div>
      <div class="to-city--code">ICN</div>
    </div>
    <div class="date">
      <div class="from-date" data-departdate="10 Apr 2017">10/04</div>
      <div class="sep">-</div>
      <div class="to-date" data-returndate="08 May 2017">08/05</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
    $('.search-content').each(function () {
        $(this).on('click', function () {
            var $fromCityCode = $('.from-city--code').html();
            console.log($fromCityCode);
        });
    });
```

Comment: The `.html()` method is doing exactly what [its documentation](http://api.jquery.com/html/) says it will do. That is, return the HTML content of the *first* element in the jQuery object it is called on. How did you expect `$('.from-city--code').html()` to know which of the several `.from-city--code` elements to use? As an aside, you don't need that `.each()` loop, you can just say `$('.search-content').on('click', ...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get that using `find() method`, as suggested `.html()` return the value of only first element, so don't use `.each()` method and console that individually.

```js
$('.search-content').on("click", function() {
  var a = $(this).find(".from-city--code").html();
  var b = $(this).find(".to-city--code").html();
  console.log(a + " " + b);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search--container">
  <div class="title">Recent searches:</div>
  <div class="search-content">
    <div class="location">
      <div class="from-city--code">KUL</div>
      <div class="sep">-</div>
      <div class="to-city--code">HKG</div>
    </div>
    <div class="date">
      <div class="from-date" data-departdate="21 May 2017">21/05</div>
      <div class="sep">-</div>
      <div class="to-date" data-returndate="29 May 2017">29/05</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="search-content">
    <div class="location">
      <div class="from-city--code">MAS</div>
      <div class="sep">-</div>
      <div class="to-city--code">SIN</div>
    </div>
    <div class="date">
      <div class="from-date" data-departdate="14 Jun 2017">14/06</div>
      <div class="sep">-</div>
      <div class="to-date" data-returndate="21 Jun 2017">21/06</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="search-content">
    <div class="location">
      <div class="from-city--code">LDN</div>
      <div class="sep">-</div>
      <div class="to-city--code">ICN</div>
    </div>
    <div class="date">
      <div class="from-date" data-departdate="10 Apr 2017">10/04</div>
      <div class="sep">-</div>
      <div class="to-date" data-returndate="08 May 2017">08/05</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to modify the jquery as:

```
$('.search-content').click(function () {
  var $fromCityCode = $(this).find('.from-city--code').html();
  console.log($fromCityCode);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put [`find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) and set `click` function directly

```
$('.search-content').on('click', function () {
    var $fromCityCode = $(this).find('.from-city--code').html();
    console.log($fromCityCode);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using class selector, which will return first element unless you iterate through the collection.

Just change

$('.from-city-code')

To

$(this).find('.from-city-code')

Hope this helps